# Pycharm Run/Debug uses Python different from one configured as an interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2016.1.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Earlier I created a virtual environment while 'tf' while having an alias of 'python' to my local installation of python 3.5+ (in case it matters).

Currently, my project interpreter is configured as

```
 "Python 3.5.1+ virtualenv at ~/tf"
```

Which corresponds to next python interpreter

```
'/home/me/tf/bin/python'
```

Yet, Debug and Run windows are starting the scripts using standard:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

At the same time "Python console" runs the correct version.
I already tried removing and re-adding the virtual environment through the interpreter configuration setting and completely removed *'/usr/bin/python3.5'* from the interpreter list. Did not help.

Any ideas where this setting pointing to *'/usr/bin/python3.5'* can linger?

Answer (score 0):

Go to project structure (File/Project Structure) `cmd + ;` on Mac.

There you can specify which SDK to use. Click `New` -> `Python` -> `Add Local` and select the `virtualnv/bin/python` file.

Comment: It is rather "Project interpreter" menu with "add local" interpreter (SDK?) button. And I tryed that already. I am pretty certain that configurations are fine, but pycharm have cached the path to an old python_setting somewhere

Comment: @yauheni_selivonchyk Please ensure that all run configurations (`Run - Edit Configurations`) use project default interpreter